# Determining Oracle Database Instance

Tags: oracle, vinstance

Other than querying the v_$database and v_$instance tables (or the views v$instance, v$database) is there any other way to programtically retrieve (from PL/SQL) the database name of an oracle database?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found the following on Experts Exchange:

```
select ora_database_name from dual;
select sys_context('userenv','db_name') from dual;
select global_name from global_name;
```

http://www.experts-exchange.com/Databases/Oracle/Q_20529577.html

Answer (score 6):

dbms_standard.database_name